# Improving speed with randomizing pairs in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to improve the speed for a routine and would love some input.
Situation is as follows:

Using the game of scrabble in a tournament setting, the following conditions apply:

1. Tournament consists of 20 or more players.
2. Number of games played is between 2 and 14, depending on tournament.
3. Players may be categorized in age divisions depending on size of tournament.

The goal is to have two special side bets for the tournament:

1. Players will be randomly paired for each game
2. Players will be randomly paired, but will have the same partner for each game.
3. A condition applies that there must be an even number of players in the side bets.
   There is a Player Table with:

ID: Integer, Name: String, Division: Integer;

There is a Sidebet Table with:

PlayerID: Integer, RandomeEachGame: Boolean, RandomAllSame: Boolean;

There is a Score Table with:

PlayerID: Integer, GameNumber: Integer, Score: Integer;

There is a RandomSidebets table with:

Player1ID: Integer;

Player2ID: Integer

GameNumber: Integer;  // Which game is score for

SameAllGames: Boolean;  // If true, then pairings is for the same partner sidebet, else it's the different partner sidebet.

I'm trying to create the random pairings, which processing seems excessive.  I'm loading the players in the specific division into a dynamic array, then I randomly pull from the dynamic array, removing that item from the array so I don't use the same player more than once per game, and do the same for the partner, then write the partner to the table to know who's partnered together.

```
    Var
        Division : integer;
    I, J     : integer;
    DSourceUsed : TIntArray;
    DSource     : TIntArray;
    rndnum     : integer;
    Fld1       : TField;


    for Division := 1 to NumberofDivisions do begin
      SQLTEXT := 'SELECT sb.PlayerID FROM SIDEBET sb ';
  SQLTEXT := SQLTEXT + ' INNER JOIN PLAYERS p ON Sb.PlayerID=p.BPlayerID ';
  SQLTEXT := SQLTEXT + Format( ' WHERE (sb.RandomEachGame=) AND (p.Division=%d)', [ Division ] );
  Qry.SQL.Text := SQLTEXT;
  Qry.Open;
  if ( Qry.RecordCount > 0 ) then begin
        if RandomMethod = mrmAllSame then begin
          SetLength( DSource, Qry.RecordCount );
          SetLength( DSourceUsed, Qry.RecordCount );
      Qry.First;
      Fld1 := Qry.FieldByName( 'PlayerID' );
          I := 0;
      while not Qry.eof do begin
        DSourceUsed[ I ] := Fld1.AsInteger;
            DSource[ I ] := Fld1.AsInteger;
            inc( I );
    Qry.Next;
      end;
          for I := 0 to Qry.RecordCount - 1 do begin
        rndnum := RandomRange( 0, Length( DSourceUsed ) - 1 );
    DSource[ I ] := DSourceUsed[ rndnum ];
    DeleteX( DSourceUsed, rndnum ); // Routine that removes index from array so we don't repeat partners
      end;
      for I := 0 to Qry.RecordCount - 1 do begin
        if not Odd( I ) then begin
              for J := 1 to NumberofGames do begin
                QryGame.SQL.Text := Format( 'INSERT INTO RandomSideBets (Player11ID, Player2ID, Game) Values (%d, %d, %d, %d)', [ DSource[ I ], DSource[ I + 1 ], J, True ] );
        QryGame.Execute;
      end;
    end;
      end;
    end
    else begin
    for J := 1 to NumberOfGames do begin
      SetLength( DSource, Qry.RecordCount );
      SetLength( DSourceUsed, Qry.RecordCount );
      Qry.First;
      Fld1 := Qry.FieldByName( 'PlayerID' );
          I := 0;
      while not Qry.eof do begin
        DSourceUsed[ I ] := Fld1.AsInteger;
    DSource[ I ] := Fld1.AsInteger;
        inc( I );
    Qry.Next;
      end;
          for I := 0 to Qry.RecordCount - 1 do begin
        rndnum := RandomRange( 0, Length( DSourceUsed ) - 1 );
    DSource[ I ] := DSourceUsed[ rndnum ];
    DeleteX( DSourceUsed, rndnum ); // Delete index from array
      end;
          for I := 0 to Qry.RecordCount - 1 do begin
        if not Odd( I ) then begin
      QryGame.SQL.Text := Format( 'INSERT INTO RANDOMSIDEBET (Player1ID, Player2ID, Game, SameAllGames) Values (%d, %d, %d, %b)', [ DSource[ I ], DSource[ I + 1 ], J, FALSE ] );
      QryGame.Execute;
    end;
      end;
        end;
      end;
end;
Qry.Close;
    end;
```

Comment: Your database engine might support a method of returning query results in random order. That would eliminate a couple of steps in your code because you could just pair up every two results you read. You *might* even be able to express the entire thing as a single `INSERT INTO SELECT` statement.

Comment: I cannot understand why you involve databases here. Isn't this just a probability question?

Answer (score 1):

You're making an inordinate amount of synchronous queries, each requiring data to get to the server and back (2*latency, plus processing time).

Either cache your inserts in an array locally, then when you're done with your algorithm send them all at once (you didn't bother to mention your SQL flavor so you're on your own), or delete that entire thing and write a stored procedure to do this on the server side (same addendum as before). The stored procedure would avoid all large data transfers between servers, being local to the server itself.

Also, maybe it's time to make use of asynchronous processing. It's 2015. Most of your CPU time is wasted waiting for I/O (the one core you even use), or doing nothing (the probably 7 other cores you paid money for).

Comment: Caching the inserts lead me to looking at transaction support.  You're right, I forgot to mention the DB.   I'm trying this with SQLite using Devart's LiteDac.  I found they support transactions.  So I wrapped the code around the loops of reading and insert statements with a .StartTransaction and a .Commit.  Was a MAJOR improvement.
I went from roughly 7485ms timing down to...  164ms.   

I'm not sure on the later part of your suggestion.  Doing asynchronous around the function to store the data. Wouldn't that be "dangerous" with the data?  (On an FTP download, I get Async).

Comment: Why would it be dangerous? That big `for` you have around your entire function, you can trivially parallelize that, gaining a straight `NumberofDivisions` times improvement for nothing. I don't do Delphi, but I'm sure it has an equivalent of thread pools or tasks or something similar. Use that!

Answer (score 0):

You only need to load the database records into a single array, and you do not need to then either sort the physical records or delete from the list to get the randomization. Instead just randomize an array of integers to act as indexes into the player list.

E.g. you load a list of 50 players (I've hardcoded 50 as an example, you would use an appropriate variable for the actual count).

```
var playerindex: array of integer;
SetLength(playerindex, 50);
for i := 0 to 50 - 1 do
    playerindex[i] := Random(50);
```

Now index into you actual player list using the playerindex values to get random pairs:

```
for pair := 0 to 50 div 2 - 1 do // 25 pairs
begin
  p1 := players[playerindex[pair * 2]];
  p2 := players[playerindex[pair * 2 + 1]];
  // record p1 and p2 as each pair of players
end;
```

Comment: That part makes sense, and I like how you set up the indexing.  The problem is that (I may not have been clear) is that while the partners are random, they have to be unique.  So if #1 was partnered with #50, then 1 or 50 can't be partners with anyone else.  So the snipped of below wouldn't work.

for i := 0 to 50 - 1 do
    playerindex[i] := Random(50);

Comment: Initialize the array with `playerindex[i] := i`. Then shuffle the array (just like a deck of cards). Take each consecutive pair.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle is simple and effective method to randomize an array

Comment: Funny, I knew the indexing would need to be unique - all 50 players represented, and had intended to write it that way but ended up not doing that for some reason. Take Rob's correction. For shuffling, you merely need to loop through all entries once, each time swapping that entry with a randomized second entry. That means a given entry *could* simply get swapped with itself, but that's ok, that's a valid randomization.

Comment: The algorithm you describe is flawed, User: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-danger-of-naivete/ Stick with Fisher-Yates.